# How to enhance Videos? (like photoshop for images)

Tags: video, windows-7, video-editing

I have a video that doesn't look quite good, is very bright with low contrast.. I need to brighten it and make it colorful with effects and plugins etc for any program that can do this.

Something like Photoshop for images..: Photoshop has an "auto-levels", "auto-contrast", and "auto-colors" ++ curve level saturation layers with which a raw image can be brightened and made to look more professional. Photoshop also has actions and Plugins available for the same purpose...

Is there any program like photoshop for videos? I only have 1 video that I want to alter, and so need suggestion for this specific requirement.

I have windows 7 64bit.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A good software for that would be CyberLink PowerDirector, but it is not free and for a one-time video edit it is not worth buying it.

Comment: Thankyou! I think @Cornelius 's answer is quite similar to what I was looking for!

Comment: Adobe After Effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/):

- freeware / open-source
- cross-platform
- can also be used for cutting, encoding videos
- compatible with many formats

After you install it, open the video file, then go to `Video` - `Filters` and choose what you want. It also has preview.

Here is an example:

[image]

And the filter options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know avidemux had those options...

Answer (score 3):

Along with Avidemux, you can also use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), another popular and open source solution. It's a bit more advanced and, by default, only takes AVI files. However, it has a bunch of filters that you can use:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Video Converter Pro](http://www.program4pc.com/video-converter-pro.html) has editing tool to enhance video such as trim, merge, crop, adjust colors and apply filter.

[image]
[image]